# Laravel changing a col name "user_id" makes $user undefined?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a strange behavior in my Laravel.

Everything was working perfectly fine, but then I decided to change the col name "user_id" to "seller_id"

And also I correctly changed the col name in the controller

```
public function transactions(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Transaction', 'seller');
}
```

Then I logged in successfully and at one point, in a view having this line:

```
auth()->user->id
```

Returned my this error:

> "Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::$user

I was looking on internet about the error and seams that I'm not logged in, but I am, any clue??

Thanks

Comment: Try replacing auth()->user->id with: auth()->user()->id

Comment: your column name should be 'seller_id' , not 'seller'

Comment: @Brad I was so obsessed into the table column change that I forgot the (), you did get the solution haha

Comment: @dasacodec changed, thanks, but Laravel is adding the id as default I think

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error you pointed out is not related to your change.

You can refer the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user), to retrieve a authenticated user you can call:

```
// Get the currently authenticated user...
$user = Auth::user();
```

Or

```
// Using helper function
$user = auth()->user()
```

Hence to retrieve a user's id:

```
$id = Auth::id();
```

Or

```
$id = auth()->id();
```

Or

```
$id = Auth::user()->id;
```

Or

```
$id = auth()->user()->id;
```

---

Also, you need to change the relationship function as [per docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many):

```
public function transactions(){
return $this->hasMany('App\Transactions', 'seller_id');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to always name your primary key with 'id' because that's default in laravel. when you have foreign keys in another table it will reference to 'table_name'_id in your case user_id

Comment: nice answer @ian vincent.